# catching DbUpdateException won't catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: entity-framework-core, nlog

I have my `db.SaveChangesAsync()` inside a try catch block as below, but checking my logs I see a log of `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` but `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` derives from `DbUpdateException`.

```
try
{
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

}
catch (DbUpdateException)
{
}
```

But I notice the following logs:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update| An exception occurred in the 
database while saving changes for context type 'xxx.MyContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database 
operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data 
may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

Didn't I catch `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` by catching `DbUpdateException` or I totally missed how exceptions work or nlog?

**edit:**

my nlog config:

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="all-log" layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}} ... />

  <target xsi:type="File" name="own-log" ... />
</targets>

<rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="all-log" />
   <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" finale="true" />
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="own-log" />
</rules>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the ASP.NET Core Logging, all components of Microsoft could write to the ASP.NET Core Logging. The NLog (NLog.Web.AspNetCore) integration will get also those logs and so you can write them to file etc.

So probably the EF component wrote that exception to the logging. You could check that by use `${stracktrace}` or `${logger}` in your config

Comment: I use `{logger}` in my config, the logger is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update`. I'll update the question with a snip of my config.

Comment: OK, but what's the question now? it's clear now that EntityFrameworkCore is creating the logevent?